# Issue to retrieve Excel file name which is more than 100 characters from SQL Server

Tags: .net

I have a .Net programme which retrieve excel from SQL Server Table. Everything was working fine.

Now a user has a file name which is more than 100 is showing a trouble. 103 to be precise. I have increased the attachment file name length to 150. So the data type look like this.

Attachment Name varchar (150) - Name of the file
AtachmentContent varbinary(MAX) - stored in the binary
AttachmentExtension varchar(5) - last 3 or 4 digits of every file.

When I run .net program, I can see the File is getting retrieved in the Debug folder. But file is not able to open after that. Excel opens with a message box which asks to 'shorten the file name'

After stopping .net execution, manually tried to open the file. It was the same message I received when I tried to launch. If I shorten the file name, I am able to open the excel file.

I am not sure what is happening here. I tried with a normal excel with almost 160 characters in the file name. That was found to be launching without any issue.

Please help.

Comment: Please show the code that is trying to open the file.  Also, is this file buried deep in a bunch of folders?  Windows has problems with long absolute path names.

Comment: yes this is in in big long path.. here - H:\Data\Ret Projects\Request Form Change\Workflow\Workflow_5_11_2018_ProductionRelease_2.1.0_After_Production_release\WorkFlow\bin\Debug

Comment: using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
                    {

                        fs.Write(documentBytes, 0, readBytes);
                        System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                        prc.StartInfo.FileName = fs.Name;
                        prc.Start();
                        //index += readBytes;

                    }

Comment: That is the code

Comment: oh you are right, i tried to move a NORMAL excel file name which is 169 character length to the temporary location. I am getting big file name message

Comment: Is there anything can be done here to look only the file name and not look at the folders

Comment: No.  That's a Windows limitation.  You could put those files somewhere else with a shorter path name (ie. dump the files in a folder off the root of the drive like "C:\excelFiles").

Comment: In the .net debug mode, the file generates in the above folder. I don't know how to control it. Seems Fs.Name takes the control. Now in RUN mode, this is completely a different folder.. C:\users.... No control either. Can you tell me how to change the location of these locations

Comment: Add the path to the constructor for your FileStream (ie. new FileStream(@"C:\myFolder\myfile.xls", ...).  Highly recommend [reading the docs on FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx).